# How to register a hover of rectangle while dragging is ongoing for other rectangle?

Tags: swiftui

In this code, I want the `green rectangle` to drag over the `blue rectangle`. When the `green rectangle` drags over the `red rectangle`, the `red rectangle` should turn `colour blue`.
I have simplified the code that it doesn't actually move when `drag`, but performs the `drag operation` under-wraps.
You can see when the `green rectangle`'s `drag operation` is going on, the `red rectangle` does not register it's `hover event`.

This view has a `scale up/down` buttons and that feature is `compulsory`.

**What methods I tried and failed,**

1. simultaneous gesture
2. creating a "NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents" and tracking if the mouse pointer is in the rectangle with "NSPointInRect(point, frame)" (This works unless if the user use the scaling buttons, but fails to update the current scaled version of the "frame" data used by "NSPointInRect`. (Basically the NSPoint thinks the rectangle is in a different place after scaling so it fails detcting the rectangle)
3. Applying the scaling factor real time to update the real time position eg: `position * scale`
4. Using geometryReader to get the position of the parent and track the position of the rectangle, but once the scale is applied it's difficult to get the actual position and feed to `NSPointInRect` to see if the mouse pointer is inside the red rectangle.

It's unfortunate that the swiftui does not provide the `minX and MinY` positions of the rectangles `real-time` so we can just refer those. It's difficult to track the position when scaling/scrolling left or right, is applied to the view.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isHovering = false
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    scale += 0.05
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                .padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    scale -= 0.05
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(isHovering ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    
                    .onHover { hovering in
                        self.isHovering = hovering && !self.isDragging
                    }
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                self.isDragging = true
                            }
                            .onEnded { gesture in
                                self.isDragging = false
                            }
                    )
                    
            } .scaleEffect(scale)
        }
    }
}
```